# How to make bodies on different layers (andengine)

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using andengine to develop my android game and ran into the following problem:

I have some bodies flying around a scene. Since they are flying in random directions, some of these bodies may collide with each other. My question is: Is there a way to make some of these bodies exist on different layers so that two bodies from two different layers will **not** collide (nor will they interact in any way)? Instead, they will simply fly one passed the other in the same direction as before the collision.

I know this can be done with sprites (as explained [here](http://www.matim-dev.com/using-entities-as-a-layers.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240420/how-do-i-build-multi-layered-scenes-with-andengine/13245162#13245162)) but can the same be done with bodies?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162837/disable-collision-completely-of-a-body-in-andengine-box2d . you dont need other layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the term I was looking for is [collision filtering](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/PhysicsCollisionFilteringExample.java). As explained and demonstrated [here](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2011/07/box2d-tutorial-collision-filtering/), filtering allows you to define which bodies can and cannot collide.